Customization In GraphQL query responses
Customization In GraphQL query responses
I want to Customizate GraphQL query responses while executing below GraphQL query.
I can do this customization using with custom content resolver but is this possible with GQL query.
I'm working with headless sitecore my sitcore version is 10.2.
Thanks in advance.
query ContentQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $contextItem, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      title {
        value
      }
      subtitle {
        value
      }     
      date {
        value
      }      
    }
  }
}

This type of response is generated upon executing the query.
{
  "data": {
    "datasource": {
     "id": "1CFDC53BCF784A4CA93C333439067205",
     "name": "About",
     "title": {        
     "value": "titlevalue"
     },
    "subtitle": {
     "value": "subtitlevalue"
     },
     "date":{
       "value": "20240305T0556002"
      }
    }
  }
}

Can we obtain the following response using a GraphQL query without any custom modifications?
{
  "data": {
    "datasource": {
     "id": "1CFDC53BCF784A4CA93C333439067205",
     "name": "About",
     "UserName": {        
     "value": "titlevalue"
     },
    "UserDetail": {
     "value": "subtitlevalue"
     },
     "DOB":{
       "value": "20240305T0556002"
      }
    }
  }
}


Hello @jammy can you please check this question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/custom-response-for-field-and-value-from-graphql-query

Praveen I have checked this question, but my requirement is different

can you please try once bellow modified query.

Yes, you can achieve this using GQL Query. As far I know using Aliases you can modify your GQL Query response.
Using the bellow modified query you can achieve it.
query ContentQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $contextItem, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      UserName: title {
        value
      }
      UserDetail: subtitle {
        value
      }
      DOB: date {
        value
      }
    }     
   }
}

Here I have added image for your reference

Hope this help!!

This can be accomplished without modifying any code. Simply adjust the GraphQL query as follows:
query ContentQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $contextItem, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      UserName: title {
        value
      }
      UserDetail: subtitle {
        value
      }     
      DOB: date {
        value
      }      
    }
  }
}

Hope this helps!!!

Yes its possible to do without any code modification. You can change the GraphQL query to as below.
query ContentQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $contextItem, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      UserName: title {
        value
      }
      UserDetail: subtitle {
        value
      }     
      DOB: date {
        value
      }      
    }
  }
}

Below is the GraphQL response.

Hope this helps!!!
